# iPhone X Game Center badge is on top of notch

Tags: ios, game-center, iphone-x

When I launch my app on the iPhone X simulator, the Game Center badge is over the notch. I've got the Storyboard to use the safe area layout guides and the rest of my app is displaying properly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Apple doesn't provide a public API to manipulate the Game Center banner, but banner notifications currently clip in a [similar way](http://pic.twitter.com/8e5qU7x9I0) on the iPhone X so it's likely that Apple will fix any notch-overlap issues in a coming build. It's also worth noting that there's no mention of this issue anywhere in the [Xcode 9 Release Notes](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9_GM_seed_build_9A235/Xcode_9_GM_seed_Release_Notes.pdf) or the [iOS 11 GM Seed Release Notes](https://download.developer.apple.com/Documentation/GM_seed_Release_Notes_Sep_12_2017/iOS_11_GM_seed_Release_Notes.pdf). They are probably aware, but it doesn't hurt to submit a radar!

Comment: I've reported this bug to Apple.